# Adding pass completion to fish shell

Tags: command-line, password, fish

I'm trying to get the CLI password manager *pass* to work in my *fish* shell with auto completion. I've already found the [necessary file](http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/plain/src/completion/pass.fish-completion), yet am having trouble finding out where to put it, or rather getting it to work. So far I've added it to:

- ~/.config/fish/pass.fish
- ~/.config/fish/completions/pass.fish
- and added the content to my ~/.config/fish/config.fish file.

with no success.

Comment: Stupid question: have you closed and reopened your shell?

Comment: Stupid questions are always appreciated: I rebooted my computer to be safe.

Comment: FYI the location of that file is no longer valid; the new location seems to be http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/completion/pass.fish-completion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second option listed (~/.config/fish/completions/pass.fish) is the preferred approach. The third should also work.

I tried the following:

1. Put the file at `~/.config/fish/completions/pass.fish`
2. Type `pass` followed by a space
3. Hit tab

And I see completions from that file.

It's possible that fish is looking somewhere else. Try `echo $fish_complete_path` and verify that it includes ~/.config/fish/completions/ . If it does not, you can put back the defaults by erasing it and starting a new session: `set -e fish_complete_path`.